# Getting "Cannot read property 'render' of undefined" in zingchart

Tags: zingchart, aurelia

I am trying to add ZingCharts to my Aurelia project. I copied and pasted the code into my Aurelia code, but when I run it, I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'render' of undefined".

I imported ZingChart using `npm zingchart`. Then I added "zingchart" to the dependencies in aurelia.json. In my aurelia javascript class, I added this to the top: `import zingchart from 'zingchart';` and copied/pasted the "My First Chart" sample code from ZingChart into the `attached` method.

Any hints would be appreciated. My code is on GitHub if you want to take a look.

https://github.com/BizArk/JobMon/tree/ZingChart/JobMonWeb

The javascript file I added ZingCharts to is in [dashboard.js](https://github.com/BizArk/JobMon/blob/ZingChart/JobMonWeb/src/dashboard/dashboard.js)

UPDATE - I still haven't solved this problem, but here are some things I've tried that didn't work...

1. Deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything (npm install)
2. Uninstalled/reinstalled aurelia-cli. It seemed to be having some trouble that I might have been related, but it is working fine now and the original problem is still not fixed.
3. Tried putting zingcharts.min.js in the prepend section. Surprisingly I am getting the same error, I expected it to be at least slightly different if I put it here.

UPDATE #2 - In zingchart/index.js, I changed the require to ../node_modules/zingchart/client/zingchart.min.js and it worked (no errors and the chart displayed). However, this can't be right. Shouldn't the path be relative to the file? Is this a bug in Gulp?

Answer (score 1):

Your format for the `aurelia.json` dependency listing is incomplete and lacks the required details.  It should be in the following minimal format:

```
{
  "name": "zingchart",
  "path": "../node_modules/zingchart",
  "main": "index"
}
```

Since I'm not familiar with the specific library, you'll have to check the **path** (to the root folder of the repo, where the main `.js` file is) and the **main** (the filename of the main `.js` file, *without* the `.js` extension).  The `from` clause of your `import` statements must match the **name** in `aurelia.json` (e.g. `import classname from "repo_name";`).

Comment: I've tried this, but when I do, I get this error. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'S:\Development\JobMon\JobMonWeb\zingchart\client\zingchart.min.js' Perhaps the problem is something else? In index.js it has a require('./client/zingchart.min.js'); It seems like it is not being relative to the zingchart library. Is there something else I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Why isn't `node_modules` being included in the path? What is the actual complete path to `zingchart.min.js`?

Comment: ../node_modules/zingchart/client. index.js is in the root "zingchart" directory. Your guess is probably better than mine why it is not looking in the node_modules directory. I am not even sure if this is a problem with Gulp or Aurelia.

Comment: Delete `/client` from your path. The root folder of your repo is just `../node_modules/zingchart`

Comment: I'm not the one putting it in the path, it's part of the require in the zingchart/index.js. I did try moving the zingchart.min.js file to the root and updating the require to look locally, but I got the same error, but different path.

Comment: And your `aurelia.json` doesn't include client, right? Alternately, you could try adding`client` to the path and using `zingchart.min` for main.  If that doesn't work, we can use the prepend option, which is for stubborn repos. I'll explain if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135477/discussion-between-brian-and-lstarky).

Comment: To use the `prepend` option, delete the normal dependency from `aurelia.json` and instead add the path to `node_modules/zingchart/index.js` (or possibly all the way to `node_modules/zingchart/client/zingchart.min.js`) to the `prepend` section of `aurelia.json` below the `requirejs` line. Change the import in your viewmodel to `import zingchart from "node_modules/zingchart/index.js";`

Comment: To whoever may be reading this, we DID NOT successfully solve the problem.  Brian (and I) would appreciate additional help.  For some reason it seems to be omitting `node_modules` in the path when it looks for the repo. See Brian's first comment above... S:\Development\JobMon\JobMonWeb\zingchart\client\zingchart.‌​min.js not found in the errors.

Comment: I found a sort-of solution, but I'm not happy with it. I changed the require in zingchart/index.js to be relative to the src folder. Seems like this isn't a reasonable fix, the build system should make paths relative to the file that the path is defined in. Am I missing something?